# Cannot use string as booleans

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector

This is driving me crazy.  I have a string that will either be `0` or `1` always.  Whenever I try to find out what it is, my application crashes.

```
if([[loggedUser isStaff] isEqualToString:@"1"])
{                         
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"staffLogin" sender:self];
}
else{
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"userLogin" sender:self];
}
```

This is what the console says:

`[740:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFBoolean
isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2d16350'`

What's going on?  I've checked the debugger and the string that it's checking for is appropriately displaying 0 and 1 as it should.

Comment: "I have a string that will either be 0 or 1 always." No, you don't. You have an `NSNumber`. Use `loggedUser.isStaff.boolValue`.

Comment: FYI, you can see right there in the error message that you don't have an NSString. See where it says `-[__NSCFBoolean isEqualToString:]`?

Comment: [@(1) boolValue] == [@"1" boolValue].. if that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[loggedUser isStaff]` seems to be an NSNumber / Boolean object yet you are trying to compare it to an NSString. Booleans and NSNUmbers do not have an isEqualToString method.

If you want to compare whether the user isStaff, you should try:

```
if ([[loggedUser isStaff] boolValue])
{
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"staffLogin" sender:self];
}
else{
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"userLogin" sender:self];
}
```

Comment: This finally did it for me.  Thanks

Comment: Since isStaff is a boolean, you can simply use if([loggedUser isStaff]){...}else{...}

Comment: It might have done it for you but its a sticking plaster if loggedUser is meant to be a string. You are corrupting it somewhere into another type. You need to find where and correct it, not fix the contents of if statement comparison.

Comment: isStaff could also be a number holding the boolean value, in which case it'll be true (not null) even if it has a value of 0.

Comment: @Cameron, no the error the OP gives shows `isStaff` returns a `__NSCFBoolean` which is a class in the `NSNumber` class cluster, as in its a subclass of `NSNumber` and as `NSNumber` is public but `__NSCFBoolean` isn't, we treat it as an `NSNumber`. What you propose will evaluate to true whether the actual Boolean value being stored in the `NSNumber` is true or false. It will only evaluate to false if `isStaff` return `nil`.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to call an `NSString` method on a boolean. You just need to check whether or not the boolean value is true.

```
if([[loggedUser isStaff] boolValue])
{                         
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"staffLogin" sender:self];
}
else{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"userLogin" sender:self];
}
```

assuming isStaff is an `NSNumber` object holding a boolean value.

```
if([loggedUser isStaff])
{                         
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"staffLogin" sender:self];
}
else{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"userLogin" sender:self];
}
```

assuming isStaff is a boolan value.

Comment: This is what my code was originally but it was ALWAYS returning true, even when the variable was 1.

Comment: Yes, because it's checking whether or not the NSNumber object is nil. You want `[[loggedUser isStaff] boolValue]` as in @valheru's answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help, he responded first I must give it to him but I upvoted you.